# Show/hide chartjs-plugin-datalabels per dataset react-chartjs-2

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

Note that this is in react and using `react-chartjs-2`.

I have a simple bar graph with 3 datasets which has `chartjs-plugin-datalabels` enabled so I can see the labels just above the bars.

Turning on a dataset which was already hidden will animate the datalabel correctly along with the bar. But the problem is, when I hide a dataset, the labels do not update so they float statically where the bar height was before I hid that dataset.

What options do I need to set for this to update along with the bars?

```
 <Bar
   data={this.state.graphData}
   legend={this.state.legendOptions}
   options={{
     plugins: {
       datalabels: {
        color: 'black',
        padding: '0',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        offset: 0,
        formatter: value => this.moneyFormat(value),
        align: 'end',
        anchor: 'end',
        display: context => context.dataset.hidden, // this needs to update ??
      },
     },
   }}
 />
```

Legend options:

```
{
  labels: {
    fontSize: 18,
    // onClick ??
  },
}
```

Thanks for the help.